# How can I realize a LAN Scanner with Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, networking

I am trying to realize an Android App that find all the devices connected in my network. Any help?

Comment: `Any help?` no, this isn't a free coding service and what you're asking is too broad and asking for library recommendations here is also off-topic. rather have a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and state what you're looking for specifically

Comment: can you provide more info and be specific about what you've tried so far and what error you're getting. don't ask for help without trying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ning](https://f-droid.org/packages/de.csicar.ning/) is an Network scanner app for Android. Good thing is it is opensource. You can take a look of its source code in [GitHub](https://github.com/csicar/Ning). If you want to build it entire application from scratch then you need to learn [NMAP](https://nmap.org/).

NMAP is an command line program specialized for network scanning. You should use it for backend and develop your android application on top of that.

Comment: The problem is that Ning is programmed in Kotlin. I am trying to do that in Java

Comment: @THOMASBERZIERI Take a look at simple network scanner app written in Java https://github.com/dmashuda/networkScanner